# Keeping indent (like breakindent) when using hard wrap with textwidth

Tags: indentation, wrapping

I know the `breakindent` option works with `linebreak` to preserve indent on wrapped lines. However, when I want to hard wrap lines (using the `textwidth` option so `<EOL>` is inserted when a line reaches the length specified by `textwidth`), `breakindent` has no effect (e.g. the new line created has no indentation). I assume `breakindent` is not intended to work with `textwidth` the way I was expecting. Is there an existing solution to this, or do I have to write a vimscript function to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`'autoindent'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html?#%27autoindent%27) option enables this behavior:

> When autoindent is on, formatting (with the `gq` command or *when you reach `'textwidth'` in Insert mode*) uses the indentation of the first line.

Note that this option has interactions with other options such as `'smartindent'` and `'cindent'`. Also, if an `'indentexpr'` is set, it can often override what `'autoindent'` does. An `'indentexpr'` is often set if you have filetype indent on, so watch out for those.

But in general, this should be enough:

```
set autoindent
```

Comment: Many thanks. Don't know how I didn't find this earlier.